# When looping through object, loop through specific property

Tags: php, laravel

I see in laravel for example, when looping through eloquent model it loops only through table attributes. For example

```
$user = new User(1);
foreach($user as $key => $value){
   echo $key.' = '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

the output will be like this

```
id=1
first_name=jone
```

It loops only through table columns although the class has other attributes

My class is like this

```
class Model {
  protected $prop1;
  protected $prop2;
  protected $columns = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'name'];
}
```

I wanna implement something like that, so when I create an object and loop through it, only loop through `$columns` propery for example

```
$model = new Model();
foreach($model as $key => $value){
       echo $key.' = '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

i need the output to be like this

```
id=1
name=name
```

Comment: Ever thought about using `in_array`? `if(in_array($key, $this->columns)) { echo ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can define how php will treat you objects in a foreach loop.
See here for the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php
By default php will iterate over all public properties.

Comment: We welcome your first answer to stackoverflow. Put some codes too. Don't just post the link.